# Passport authenticate callback is not passed req and res

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

this authenticate works fine and I get a redirect:

```
server.post(authPostRoute, passport.authenticate(
    'local'
    , { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }
));
```

this authenticate hangs after the call back is called:

```
server.post(authPostRoute, passport.authenticate(
    'local'
    , function(){ console.log('Hitting the callback'); console.log(arguments)}
));
```

this logs the following piece:

```
{ '0': null,
  '1':
   { id: [Getter/Setter],
     firstName: [Getter/Setter],
     lastName: [Getter/Setter],
     email: [Getter/Setter],
     addedOn: [Getter/Setter],
     active: [Getter/Setter],
     password: [Getter/Setter] },
  '2': undefined }
```

But throughout the documentation (http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/)  it looks as though it shuold be passed req and res, but it obviously isn't.  Then the code that calls the callback:

node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js

```
  strategy.success = function(user, info) {
    if (callback) {
      return callback(null, user, info);
    }
```

doesn't pass those parameters.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, I was working on ripping out my custom authentication and replacing it with passport for 9 hours yesterday.  Between getting the node-orm to expos the model outside of the request and dealing with the flow of ordering things I was a little burned out.  THe code examples are accurate, I just needed to read more carefully:

```
// traditional route handler, passed req/res
server.post(authPostRoute, function(req, res, next) {

  // generate the authenticate method (the anonymous method) and
  //     associate it with the 'local' strategy
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }

    // req / res held in closure
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.send(user);
    });

  })(req, res, next);

});
```

Comment: in passport.authenticate() what is err,user,info parameters?

Comment: It has been a long time since I have worked with this, but I believe that when passport is configured you provide it a function which takes a UN / PWD which you can then authenticate against your source (this happens within the passport.authenticate('local',...) That implementation provides the values err and user.  I am certain it provides info as well - but I cannot remember the inteded use of that field.

Comment: The err,user,info parameters are coming as null,false,missing credentials, can you know what is mistake. refer my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898027/passport-js-local-strategy-custom-callback-showing-user-as-false-and-info-as-mi

Comment: @charantej do you have any idea why err, user, info parameters are not null, false and missing as normal? Err is `[{"id":1,"email":"a@gmail.com","password":"a"}]`, user and info are `undefined`

Comment: I am new to javascript. So what is `(req, res, next);` after the `passport.authenticate()` function for?

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly, but you might serarch for "continutation passing style" and the alternative approach "promises" to help you get familiar with js.

Answer (score 2):

Enable passReqToCallback to get the request in callback. Like this:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: '555555555555555',
    clientSecret: '555555555555555555555',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    enableProof: false,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  // The request will be provided as 1st param
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  });...
```

Comment: This will pass it to the *strategy* callback, not to the *authenticate* callback. But since you can define your own strategy callback, which you can call the authenticate callback from, you can pass it req as well.