# 400 ( bad request ) using fetch to login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, fetch

I am attempting to use fetch to POST a login form my to login function using passport.

The login works when using the standard form action="/login", but I wanted to go over to fetch to be able to show realtime error output if login fails without refresh...

I am getting 400 ( bad request ) and Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 when sending a login request...

here's my code:

```
let payload = {
  username: "user1@user1.se",
  password: "superman123"
};

let data = new FormData();
data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

console.log(data);
fetch('/login', {
  method: 'post',
  body: data
}).then(function(response) {
  // if (response.status >= 400) {
  //     throw new Error("Bad response from server");
  // }
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And here's my passport code:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var db = require('./db');


// Configure the local strategy for use by Passport.
//
// The local strategy require a `verify` function which receives the credentials
// (`username` and `password`) submitted by the user.  The function must verify
// that the password is correct and then invoke `cb` with a user object, which
// will be set at `req.user` in route handlers after authentication.
passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
      console.log("1");
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));


// Configure Passport authenticated session persistence.
//
// In order to restore authentication state across HTTP requests, Passport needs
// to serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  The
// typical implementation of this is as simple as supplying the user ID when
// serializing, and querying the user record by ID from the database when
// deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  db.users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    cb(null, user);
  });
});
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/',
  require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn("/login"),
  function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/app/index.html'));
  });

app.get('/login',
  function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/app/public.html'));
  });


    app.post('/login', 
      passport.authenticate('local'),
      function(req, res) {
          console.log("post")
        res.redirect('/');
      });

    app.get('/logout',
      function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
      });
```

**EDIT 1**
I was getting Uncaught `(in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0` due to trying to parse an undefined response in .then(). But i still get the 400 error message.. Am I sending the data wrong?

**EDIT 2**

I modified my code to this, and now I am getting response.ok = true, however I get that even if I send the wrong login details... Do I need to update my strategy?

```
passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));



app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    switch (req.accepts('html', 'json')) {
      case 'html':
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          return res.redirect('/');
        });
        break;
      case 'json':
        if (err)  { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.status(401).send({"ok": false}); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) { return res.status(401).send({"ok": false}); }
          return res.send({"ok": true});
        });
        break;
      default:
        res.status(406).send();
    }
  })(req, res, next);    
});
```

Comment: What happens if you just sent `body: JSON.stringify(payload)` ?  Does the fetch function require `Content-Type` to be set ?

Comment: Still getting 400 (bad request). I am assuming something is wrong with this: app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) { res.redirect('/'); }); @Searching I assume its not picking up the fetch request

Comment: going by the parse error try this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26032067/1339516](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26032067/1339516)

Comment: @Searching thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Now I dont get the 400 error, and I get response.ok = true, however it gives me that even if I send wrong login parameters. Can you check my updated first post?

Comment: Hmm.. I would probably start putting some `console.log()` statements out the node terminal of  `req`.. See if you can also use `info` and `user` argument to see what happened `authenticate` function. Probably there is no exception which `err` carries but just something else might be invalid or valid. It will be good to check if its actually hitting the json update you made.

Comment: I have same problem and solution is CSRF token.