# No redirect on failed passport authentication

Tags: node.js, passport.js

New to nodejs, liking it so far, trying to do some custom handling for passport authentication. The success redirect works fine, however upon an unsuccessful attempt i would like to not continue the post event.
What I'm trying to accomplish is fire an alert off that opens a dialog (this part is working like I want, via the socket call) to the current page if there is an issue with the login attempt. 
The browser just waits if I don't call res.send() for example, or attempts to redirect to a page that does not exist if I do.

routes.js

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err, user, msg) {
        if (err) {
            io.emit('status alert', err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            io.emit('status alert', msg);
            //res.send();
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                io.emit('status alert', err);
            }
            if (user) {
                return res.redirect('/loginsplash');
            }
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

passport.js

```
passport.use(
    'local-login',
    new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function (req, username, password, done) {
        db.getConnection().query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = ?", [username], function (err, rows) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!rows.length) {
                return done(null, false,  'Invalid Username or Password.');
            }

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].upw))
                return done(null, false, 'Invalid Username or Password.');

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, rows[0]);
        });
    })
);
```

Comment: What you want after you successfully send the socket request ?

Comment: Basically nothing to happen on the routing side. I've done what I wanted at that point.

Comment: Just use `res.end();`

Comment: Had tried that one, still sends it to /login, which doesn't actually exist

Comment: See `res.end()` will just kill your current request and nothing goes to the browser so it show a pages with was request from client end, but server responds with no value, let me know which page you want to display then ?

Comment: yeah i think i understand. it sounds like i might need to come up with a different strategy, maybe ajax based to validate credentials before submitting the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a weekend of persistence and trial/error, my hunch to use ajax seems to be right. I finally came across a similar so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019995/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-data-for-passportjs) that was helpful. Hope this helps someone else, I'm probably going to tweak it some, but right now basically if the ajax response is empty (res.end), my custom dialog pops up. If there's something in it (from the res.redirect), it redirects to the intended page :

passport.js, no changes from above

routes.js

```
app.post('/login/ajax', function (req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err, user, info) {
                    if (err) { return next(err); }
                    if (!user) { return res.end(); }
                    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                        if (err) { return next(err); }
                        return res.redirect('/loggedin');
                    });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

ajax call in .ejs page

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login/ajax",
        data: { username: username , password: password },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
          window.location.href = '/loginsplash';
          }
          else {
            OpenFeedbackMsgDlg("Login Failed");
          }
        }
      }).done(function () {
                console.log("http request succeeded");
                alert("login success");
            });
    });
```

If anyone has suggestions/alternate approaches, I'd still be interested in learning.